# Django is redirecting me to sublime text and the last raises import error

Tags: django, sublimetext3

Have chosen Sublime as core git editor. And now after every move I do in Django virtual project, i'm being redirecting to sublime text with such error:

```
raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
```

Comment: If your question relates to you changing the `git` core editor, why isn't your question tagged as `git` as well? In any case, your question is quite unclear; what operations are making the errors appear? where are they showing up? what should be happening instead?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check you selected the current python interpreter for your project. Since you are on a virtual environment, you should check the python interpreter is the same as the one created in the virtual environment, not the general interpreter.

Comment: Thanks. The interpreter is proper.